# How to remove a dictionary from a list of dictionaries (using a given value)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Essentially I was trying to remove a designated dictionary inside a list of dictionaries but unfortunately the loop I was coding only worked to delete the first dictionary and did not recognise the rest of the dictionaries within that same list. The code was similar to the one following:

```
list=[{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"}, 
{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"},
{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"}]

def drop_dic():

    print("please insert value you want to remove")
    value3=input()
    
    for i in range(len(list)):
        
        if list[i]["key3"] == value3:
            
            key1_drop = vip_list[i]["key1"]
            key2_drop = vip_list[i]["key2"]
            
            del list[i]
            
            print ( key1_drop + " and " + key2_drop + " have been removed.")
            
            break
            
        else:
    
            print("This dict doe not exist")
        
            break
```

Basically if I try to remove the first dictionary from the list using the first key3 I am able to, but the rest of the dicts it just prints "this dict does not exist"

What should I change?

What is the best and simplest way to remove an identified dict from a list of dicts following a given value?

Comment: I do not recommend you use Python keywords as variable, as it can probably break the program. Change `list` to something else like `lst` or `list1` for example.

Comment: Also, where is `vip_list` defined?

Comment: Your `else` statement shouldn't be there.  If the first dictionary doesn't pass the test, you're immediately going to the `else` statement and breaking out of the loop.  Plus all the stuff said by the other commentors.

Comment: If you put your `else:` at the same level as the for-loop, it will be executed only if no match was found (i.e. if the loop was not broken by a break statement).

Comment: Thank you guys!! I just thought you could only use an '''else:''' on the same level as the prior if statement and not before it. Makes it a bit confusing for me tbh, I'm pretty new to python

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on. First, you have a `break` statement in your `if` clause. Thus, once there is a match, the loop will stop and you will not delete the other instances.

More importantly, though, you are editing the contents of a list while iterating through it, which is something to be avoided. A better strategy would be to copy the current list to a new list with just the contents you want.

```py
vip_list=[
    {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"}, 
    {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"},
    {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"}
]

remove_value = "value3"

filtered_vip_list = [elem for elem in vip_list if elem["key3"] != remove_value]
```